# Is it possible to apply "Material Design" in the Portable project (Android and iOS)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I just found Xamarin.Droid application references, however I want to apply "Material Design" in a Portable project.

It does not matter if iOS does not use "Material Design", I just want to use the portable project for iOS as well.

I would like my Entry component

```
<Entry x: Name = "user" Placeholder = "User" Text = "{Binding User}" />
```

Look like the image below.

[image: Material Design]

I tried some sites, however all developers do not do with portable project.
They use Xamarin for development, but they develop with project Xamarin.Droid and Xamarin.iOS

[Tutorial](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55192/material-textinputlayout-renderer-floating-labels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin does not have its own UI component library. The code that you mentioned:

`<Entry x: Name = "user" Placeholder = "User" Text = "{Binding User}" />`

is Xamarin Forms xaml markup code. Xamarin Forms is an abstraction over native iOS and Android components. So basically the `Entry` component will become native text entry field at runtime (`UITextField` on iOS and `EditText` on Android).

Now Material design is Android specific. That means that `Entry` component will look like in your attached gif only on Android.
However you can customize the behavior of Xamarin Forms components using [custom renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/).